# Modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I am new to Haskell. I am extremely confused about modules, what they are, and how to use them. For example, I created a `add.hs` file that contains a simple function as follows:

```
add a b = a + b
```

There are some test cases in a file called `addTestCases.hs`, that check for the functionality of `add.hs`.

I am somehow supposed to load the testcases to GHC, which will automatically run, and find the `add.hs` function.

I am really not sure how to accomplish this, and would appreciate any clarification, as I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Add.hs` you declare the module name:

```
-- Notice the module name matches the file name, this is typically required
module Add where

add :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add x y = x + y
```

And in Test.hs you tell it which modules the functions come from:

```
-- Notice we didn't declare a module name, so it defaults to 'Main'
import Add
import Test.QuickCheck
main = quickCheck (\ x y -> x > 0 && y > 0 ==> add x y > x && add x y > y)
```

You can now compile and run your tests:

```
$ ghc Test.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Add              ( Add.hs, Add.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
$ ./Test
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

EDIT:

And if you are working inside of GHCi, and vs compiling from a terminal as shown above, then you can do:

```
... run "ghci Test.hs" ...
> main
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am having a tough time running the test cases however. I created two files `Add.hs` and `Test.hs`, then when I try to run test cases in GHCi by typing `$ ghc Test.hs` I keep getting a parse error.

Comment: @MHZ You are supposed to enter `ghc Test.hs` into a shell prompt (or a command prompt window on Windows) (as indicated by the `$`). You are *not* supposed to enter it into ghci.

Comment: @MHZ In many online forums, and certainly SO, the `$` is ment to indicate a shell on some unix-like system (and sometimes a Windows terminal is acceptable).  I edited the question with an example using GHCi instead of compiling via GHC. Just to be clear: GHC is a compiler while GHCi is an interpreter - you do not typically invoke a compiler from within an interpreter and the Haskell ecosystem is no exception.

Comment: Watch out for `Int`eger overflow!

*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 64 tests and 15 shrinks):     
1219012583
928471065

Comment: @pat lol, thanks!  I should have made a silly example that showed it was associative or just used Integer.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the help fellas. I did not know that. I never had to work on a Unix-like system before, so it did not occur to me that your code was for Unix command line. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add `module Add where` as the first line of your add.hs file. Then all the functions you define in the file, will be inside the module `Add` and can be imported from other files by writing `import Add` in those files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, your explanation doesn't really make sense to me, can you please try to explain it in a simpler way? Suppose I just opened GHC and I have a file with add.hs that contains a function, and a file with addTests.hs that I need load into GHC for testing, I don't understand how typing `module Add where` helps me test?

Comment: @MHZ Can you be more specific about which part doesn't make sense to you? I thought what I wrote was simple.

Comment: When you say 'in your first line' do you mean in GHC or in the add.hs file?

Comment: @MHZ I meant in the add.hs file. And I'm not sure what you mean by "GHC" - you can't write stuff into GHC, GHC doesn't read input. Do you mean GHCI?

Comment: Yes, GHC stands for Glasgow Haskell Compiler. GHCi is what I use as the interface. I presumed GHC was clear enough, guess it wasn't ;)

Comment: @MHZ I know what GHC stands for, but surely you realize that ghc and ghci are two different tools that serve two different functions, yes? So why should I assume you mean one when you say the other?